# How to obtain the value selected from list

Tags: javascript, html

I have created html page, which has a list displaying the "name of cars".
I need to obtain the value selected from the list and post a request sending the "selected value" argument.

I could do it with button

```
<button onclick = "postreq('/../..path',{param_name= "fjskhfs"},func_to_handleonclick);">
</button>
```

Can anyone guide me to do the same with select option ??? 
It will be of great help...
Thank you...

Comment: you can try onchange event of select conttrol

Comment: Syntax in inline onclick handler is wrong. If you provide second parameter as an object you should use colon `:`, instead of assigning operator `=`, and also double quotes don't match, escape inner scopes `\"`, or use single quotes `'`.

Comment: Also, if you don't want to make asynchronous request, you don't need any javascript for this, wrap your list with form tag. Look at: [HTML forms guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms) and [<form>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code template;

**HTML:**

```
<select id="cars">
    <option value="car1">Car1</option>
    <option value="car2">Car2</option>
    <option value="car3">Car3</option>
    <option value="car4">Car4</option>
</select>

<input type="button" name="send_cars" value="Send" id="send_cars"/>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#send_cars").click(function() {
        alert("Car: " + $("#cars :selected").val() + " will be sent as request param");
        $.ajax({
            url: "your_url",
            data: "car=" + $("#cars :selected").val(),
            method: "POST",
            success: function() {

            }
        })
    });
})
```

You can see working fiddle here: **http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/Y5vKs/1/**

If you want to use pure js, you can use following code structure;

**JS:**

```
function postreq(url, param_value, callback) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("param_name=" + car_id);
}

function func_to_handleonclick(result) {
    alert("Result is: " + result);
}

function getSelectedCar() {
    var e = document.getElementById("car_selectbox_id");
    var car_value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    return car_value
}
```

**Usage:**

```
postreq("your_url", getSelectedCar(), func_to_handleonclick);
```

Comment: There's no JQuery tag.

Comment: I suggest user to use jQuery

Comment: I have also added pure js version

Comment: I think you should rename your "Pure JS" label to "JS" and rename the "JS" label to "jQuery".

Comment: Thank you all for the reply. and more thanks to Huseyin BABAL Sir. JQuery code helped a lot for my program. :) :)

Comment: You can approve my answer if your problem resolved :-)